# Does a partial traversal of a linked-list count as "one pass" of the list?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, linked-list

I've been going through algorithm challenges on LeetCode and just completed "Remove Nth Node From End of List".

Many of the top answers claimed to have found a "one pass" solution and I've included a Java example below.

Please could someone explain why "while(n-->0) h2=h2.next;" doesn't count as an extra pass of the linked list and, therefore, make this a "two pass" solution?

```
public ListNode RemoveNthFromEnd(ListNode head, int n)  {
    ListNode h1=head, h2=head;

    while(n-->0) h2=h2.next;

    if(h2==null)return head.next;  // The head need to be removed, do it.

    h2=h2.next;
    
    while(h2!=null){
        h1=h1.next;
        h2=h2.next;
    }
    h1.next=h1.next.next;   // the one after the h1 need to be removed
    return head;
}
```

I've looked in the comments to this and other solutions and couldn't find an answer. Equally, a general Google search didn't yield an explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link(s) would be good.

Comment: The challenge on LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/ 
Also if it helps, the example solution: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/discuss/8806/My-one-pass-solution

Comment: See the discussion in [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/discuss/8804/Simple-Java-solution-in-one-pass) for example. It seems like whether this is "one pass" or not is disputed.

Comment: I managed to catch your first answer shortly before it was deleted, but it explained exactly what I was looking for - the fact that the list is traversed in two parts: 1 to n in the first loop and the rest of the list in the second. Thank you!

Comment: It could be that those who call this a "one pass" solution actually *mean* it is a O(n) solution -- which is true.

Comment: @trincot That would not be noteworthy, though. What solution to this *isn't* O(n)?

Comment: @Yves, I also meant *n* as the length of the list (which is the worst case for the argument `n`). It is an O(n) algorithm, and like Kelly said, any reasonable algorithm for this job would be O(n).

Comment: @trincot: no reasonable challenge designer would call O(n) "single pass".

Comment: Maybe, but the people discussing it on the referenced page are not guaranteed to be reasonable nor to be challenge designers ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not one-pass. One-pass is defined with respect to a sequential I/O mechanism (canonically a tape) and means that each piece of data is read at most once, in order. Analogizing the linked list to the tape here, this algorithm is not one-pass because in general, some node will have its `next` field read once by `h2=h2.next` (in either loop) and again by `h1=h1.next` in the second loop.

Comment: I think the algorithms for this that *do* count as one pass can generally follow N+O(k) next pointers to remove the kth node from the end of an N-length list.

Comment: @MattTimmermans No, there's no in-place one-pass algorithm for this because we have to read past the node that we need to change in order to know that we need to change it.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: I don't think that this criterion is sufficient. The pass need not be partial to be called a pass.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat the easy way is to sample the node pointer when position%k == 0, and remember the last 2 samples.  When you get to the end of the list, you can calculate the distance between the earliest remembered sample and the target node.  It will be <= k.  That is not one-pass by your definition, but it's what passes for one-pass in the online discussions of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm is not single pass, but not because of the first loop.

The first loop performs a partial pass on `n` elements.

The second loop performs two simultaneous partial passes on `l-n` elements (that on `h2` being complementary to that in the first loop). In total, `2l-n` lookups of `next` fields.

A single-pass solution can be implemented with the help of a FIFO queue of length `n`, but this is "hiding" a partial pass.